# How to write dynamic query in SQL inorder to get the sum of same columns from different tables by using union or cross joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query to get to know the sums of same columns across all the tables.

```
select sum(column1),sum(column2) from
(
  select t1.column1 as column1, 0.00 as column2 from table1 t1
  union all
  select 0.00 as column1, t2.column1 as column2 from table2 t2
)
```

Tried below query

```
select t1.column1, t2.column1 from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

but it is not working and it is taking a very very long time

Please suggest to me the best approach.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for the response
but I have tried the below query but it is running like forever .

Please suggest union or cross join one with dynamic query

Comment: What is wrong with your `UNION ALL` query you started with?

Comment: Nothing Wrong with that Charlieface I want to make that query as dynamic one.

Thats the challenge actually.

Comment: So what's the question *exactly*? And what's dynamic about your second one? You don't mention the word "dynamic" anywhere in the question? WHat do you want to make dynamic?

Answer (score -1):

With union or complex queries, you may get long time responses. Instead of union or join, you can use multiple tables in one **FROM** condition. I may suggest two example methods for your question:

**1. For separately total column sum response:**

```sql
Select
    sum(categories.id),
    sum(form_elements.id),
    sum(users.id)
From users,categories,form_elements;
```

**2. Total sum of all table columns:**

```sql
Select
    ( sum(categories.id) +
    sum(form_elements.id) +
    sum(users.id) ) as total_sum
From users,categories,form_elements
```

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for the response

But i have tried this one it is not working i mean this query is running like forever.

Please suggest the other one in dynamic query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged